# firebase signin did not run anything

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm making login Authentication with **Firebase** and I'm testing it with creating a user ID and password on authentication **Firebase** and test login with that email and password. But I got no response both correct password and wrong password. Please help!

```html
<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.2/firebase-app.js"></script>

<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.2/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
 <!-- Add Firebase products that you want to use -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.2/firebase-firestore.js"></script>

<script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "....",
    authDomain: "....",
    databaseURL: "....",
    projectId: "....",
    storageBucket: "....",
    messagingSenderId: "....",
    appId: "....",
    measurementId: "...."
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();
</script>

<script>
    document.getElementById("idLogin").onclick = function() {

    var email = document.getElementById('idUser').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('idPassword').value;

    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(function(){
            alert('login success');
            console.log('success');
        }).catch(function(error) {
            alert('login fail');
            console.log('error');
        })
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show the code for your `idLogin` button (including the code around it, e.g. the `form` tags)

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Here https://i.imgur.com/faqAndw.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is most probably happening is that since the element with `id="idLogin"` is of type `submit` your form is submitted **before** the Firebase `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` method is triggered.

You need to explicitly specify the button type as `button`, (and not `submit`) as follows:

```
<button type="button" id="idLogin">Login</button>
```

See the [W3 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#the-button-element) for more detail.

Comment: or bind to the form's onsubmit handler instead.